# Creating Method for Deserialized Type Array in C#

Tags: c#, json, rest, httpwebrequest

```
public static string GetTruth(){
// code here
return "done";
}
```

This returns a String

```
public static int GetTruth(){
returns 1;
}
```

Returns True or False in Case of 0 or 1

```
public static bool GetTruth(){
return true;
}
```

Returns true or false

Now i want to return an Array of Objects from a Json String, So I can get the data from the REST api and use in another Application
Now I am using something like this

```
public static JObject GETRESTSimulator{
return obj
}
```

How Can i go about getting it into a `Deserialized Type Array`

My Code is looking Something Like this

```
public static Object[] GETRESTInfo(string restUrl, string reqMethod) 
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(restUrl);
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(responseString);

        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>`, which makes a List, if you need to return an array?

Comment: @gunr2171 i know I missed something, kindly point me in the right Direction

Comment: Try `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[]>(responseString);`

Comment: Done that, Does not Work as supposed, it Does not Return a Deserialized Typed Array.